# When form submitted then all rows take one value

Tags: php, mysql

I am newbie in PHP and with this less knowledge of PHP i developed a form to update the rows of MySQL table. But the problem is that if i edit one row in index.php file and submit it then that row value comes to all rows of the table.

I want to change the edited inputs and the rest inputs should be unchanged.

Please note that first row budget value will be added when second row budget  value and will be inserted in total input and will save to database

[This is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEF06.png)

this is the index.php file

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","","ji001");
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM finance")
or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($con));

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{   $Budget = $row['Budget'];
     $Availed_in_Regions = $row['Availed_in_Regions'];


echo "<form style='width:780px' action='update2.php' method='post' class='form-group'>
id<input type='text' name='Budget' value='".$row['ID']."'>
Budget<input type='text'  name='Budget' value='".$row['Budget']."'>
Availed in Regions <input type='text' name='Availed_in_Regions' value='".$row['Availed_in_Regions']."'>
<input type='Submit'>
</form>";
}
?>
```

This is the update2.php file

```
   <?php
    mysql_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '') or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("ji001") or die(mysql_error());

    $ud_Budget = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["Budget"]);
    $ud_Availed_in_Regions = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["Availed_in_Regions"]);

    $query="UPDATE finance SET Budget = '$ud_Budget', Availed_in_Regions = '$ud_Availed_in_Regions'";


mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_affected_rows()>=1){
    echo "<p>Record Updated<p>";
}else{
    echo "<p>Not Updated<p>";
}

?>
```

Comment: Firstly, your form having typo **id** and **name** having same name for the **name** attribute i.e. **name='Budget'**

Comment: Thanks @NarendraSisodia can you help me to do that. thanks

Comment: I have updated my answer you can check it now @user3773852

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, your form having typo id and name having same name for the name attribute i.e. name='Budget'

**index.php**

```
echo "<form style='width:780px' action='update2.php' method='post' class='form-group'>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{  

  $Budget = $row['Budget'];
  $Availed_in_Regions = $row['Availed_in_Regions'];

 echo "id<input type='text' name='id[]' value='".$row['ID']."'>

  Budget<input type='text'  name='Budget[]' value='".$row['Budget']."'>

  Availed in Regions <input type='text' name='Availed_in_Regions[]' value='".$row['Availed_in_Regions']."'>";

}

echo "<input type='Submit' value='Submit'></form>";
```

and you need to change your update query from

**update2.php**

```
$ud_id = $_POST["id"];
$ud_Budget = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_POST['Budget']);
$ud_Availed_in_Regions = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string',$_POST["Availed_in_Regions"]);

foreach($ud_id as $key => $value){
    $query = "UPDATE finance SET Budget = '$ud_Budget[$key]', Availed_in_Regions = '$ud_Availed_in_Regions[$key]' where ID = $value";
    mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
   if(mysql_affected_rows()>=1){
      echo "<p>Record Updated<p>";
   }else{
      echo "<p>Not Updated<p>";
   }
}
```

Here I have added `where` condition which is required to identify which row you need to update and

> NOTICE : You were mixing two API within index.php you were using **mysqli_** and within update2.php its **mysql**

Comment: Thanks a lot @Sisodia, it works good but if i edit two rows then when i click on submit button it update only one row not the other rows which have been changed.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using a where clause in the $query query.
it should be something like this

```
$query="UPDATE finance SET Budget = '$ud_Budget', Availed_in_Regions = '$ud_Availed_in_Regions' WHERE id = '$id'";
```

You should also pass this id in the form, also change the name of the input field containing the id...

Answer (score 0):

Because you actually `SELECT` every row in your table.

`UPDATE finance SET Budget = '$ud_Budget', Availed_in_Regions = '$ud_Availed_in_Regions';`

There is no `WHERE` clause ([link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp)) in your query you have to use it if you wanna update a row in your table.

Pass `$id` to your `update2.php` and use this query instead:

`UPDATE finance SET Budget = '$ud_Budget', Availed_in_Regions = '$ud_Availed_in_Regions' WHERE id = '$id';`

Comment: Thanks @sky i want to save the form not a row, because each row have a relationship of plus i mean first row budget value plus second row budget value will be entered in total and will save.